# Use custom SpiderMonkey build with firefox 5

Tags: firefox, spidermonkey, javascript-engine

I am trying to build and use SpiderMonkey I compiled (for my academic research) with firefox 5 on a windows machine, but when I try to run firefox I get "missing JS_InitCTypesClass function in mozjs.dll" error.

I downloaded SpiderMonkey code and I built it (without any changes) using MozillaBuild.
Than I copied to new DLL to the firefox directory (renaming the DLL name to mozjs.dll) and tried to execute firefox. At this point I got the error I wrote.

Also, checking using exported function viewer I noticed that the original mozjs.dll has 777 exported functions, while the one I compiled has only 771 functions, so I guess the function is really missing.

Any ideas how can I build a custom SpiderMonkey and use it with FF5 ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you `--enable-ctypes` when configuring your spidermonkey?

Comment: *glup* - no. :-) how do I do that? "Configure --enable-ctypes" ?

Comment: Okay, built with CTypes. Also needed to build NSPR. Now it looks for "JS_HoldPrincipals" exported functions. I guess that now I need to find out which "switch" enables that...

Comment: `JS_HoldPrincipals` is dependent on `--enable-threadsafe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to make sure that the way you configure SpiderMonkey matches what happens at http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/a0372b031aac/configure.in#l9484

Comment: Took me a while. It turned out I was building the nightly version (although I didn't take the code from nightly.mozillla.com but mozilla-central).
Anyway, Got the right version, build it like you said (I Also needed to build NSPR) and worked like a charm. Thanks :-).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of anyone successfully replacing spidermonkey in a release Firefox build like that; the sure way to get your own version of SpiderMonkey used in Firefox would be to [make your own Firefox build](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Simple_Firefox_build).

Anyway, where did you get the Spidermonkey source? You should at least use the one corresponding to the Firefox release you're using, e.g.: http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/rev/3ded311d93ad

Comment: Hmm... maybe you're right, maybe I didn't get the right version (I downloaded it from their Mercurial). I'll recheck it. If it won't work I guess I will rebuild FF...

Comment: Seems like I got the right SpiderMonkey version. I really don't know why it doesn't work :-\.

I don't want to get into building the whole FF, but I guess I won't have any other choice...